# Order result from ajax

Tags: posts, ajax

I have a code that return live post updates to me, but there is something wrong on it.

When new post published it's get under other post, i want to have it over other posts.

My code:

```
<div class="latest-news">
      <?php 
        $current_posts_ids = array();
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
          <div class="posts">
            <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
              <?php array_push($current_posts_ids, get_the_ID() );?>
              <article data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID()?>">
                <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_excerpt() ?><p>
              </article>
            <?php endwhile ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif ?>
 </div>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

      var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";   
      var dataArray =  <?php echo json_encode($current_posts_ids) ?>;

      function getMyPosts() {

            data = { action: "update_news", data: dataArray};
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                // reset array
                dataArray = [];
                // append the new news posts                
                $('.latest-news .posts').append(response);
                // create new array of ids to exclude
                $('article').each(function(){
                    dataArray.push($(this).data('id'));  
                }); 
                // repeat function after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getMyPosts();
                }, 5000)
            });

     }
     //run the function first time
     getMyPosts();   

});
</script>
```

Comment: Took a quick look and I think you can just change `append` to `prepend` in your jQuery on this line `$('.latest-news .posts').append(response);`

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

      var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";   
      var dataArray =  <?php echo json_encode($current_posts_ids) ?>;

      function getMyPosts() {

            data = { action: "update_news", data: dataArray};
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                // reset array
                dataArray = [];
                // append the new news posts                
                $('.latest-news .posts').prepend(response);
                // create new array of ids to exclude
                $('article').each(function(){
                    dataArray.push($(this).data('id'));  
                }); 
                // repeat function after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getMyPosts();
                }, 5000)
            });

     }
     //run the function first time
     getMyPosts();   

});
</script>
```